# How do I write a simple HTTPS proxy server in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, proxy

I've seen several examples of writing an HTTP proxy in Ruby, e.g. [this gist by Torsten Becker](https://gist.github.com/74107), but how would I extend it to handle HTTPS, aka for a "man in the middle" SSL proxy?

I'm looking for a simple source code framework which I can extend for my own logging and testing needs.

#### update

I already use [Charles, a nifty HTTPS proxy app](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) similar to Fiddler and it is essentially what I want except that it's packaged up in an app.  I want to write my own because I have specific needs for filtering and presentation.

#### update II

Having poked around, I understand the terminology a little better.  I'm NOT after a full "Man in the Middle" SSL proxy.  Instead, it will run locally on my machine and so I can honor whatever SSL cert it offers.  However, I need to see the decrypted contents of packets of my requests and the decrypted contents of the responses.

Answer (score 8):

Just for background information, a normal HTTP proxy handles HTTPS requests via the `CONNECT` method: it reads the host name and port, establishes a TCP connection to this target server on this port, returns `200 OK` and then merely tunnels that TCP connection to the initial client (the fact that SSL/TLS is exchanged on top of that TCP connection is barely relevant).

This is what the `do_CONNECT` method if [`WEBrick::HTTPProxyServer`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick/HTTPProxyServer.html).

If you want a MITM proxy, i.e. if you want to be able to look inside the SSL/TLS traffic, you can certainly use `WEBrick::HTTPProxyServer`, but you'll need to change `do_CONNECT completely`:

- Firstly, your proxy server will need to embed a mini CA, capable of generating certificates on the fly (failing that, you might be able to use self-signed certificates, if you're willing to bypass warning messages in the browser). You would then import that CA certificate into the browser.
- When you get the `CONNECT` request, you'll need to generate a certificate valid for that host name (preferable with a Suject Alt. Name for that host name, or in the Subject DN's Common Name), and upgrade the socket into an SSL/TLS server socket (using that certificate). If the browser accepts to trust that certificate, what you get from thereon on this SSL/TLS socket is the plain text traffic.
- You would then have to handle the requests (get the request line, headers and entity) and take it to use it via a normal HTTPS client library. You might be able to send that traffic to a second instance of `WEBrick::HTTPProxyServer`, but it would have to be tweaked to make outgoing HTTPS requests instead of plain HTTP requests.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks! After grokking this I was able to create a custom `WEBrick::HTTPProxyServer` subclass that simply commented out a section of [the original](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/lib/webrick/httpproxy.rb) `do_CONNECT` method to avoid sending the CONNECT handshake, which then let me point the `ProxyURI` param at the port of a standard `WEBrick::HTTPServer` instance that has self-signed certs (since I'm skipping validation in my use case). This worked great, I can use the first server as an HTTPS proxy and the second as a MITM server that can hijack responses.

Answer (score 1):

Webrick can proxy ssl:

```
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/httpproxy'
WEBrick::HTTPProxyServer.new(:Port => 8080).start
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a MITM proxy, but like a normal HTTP(S) proxy.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if webrick can forge certs or any such thing, I've never tried.

Comment: I'm no Ruby expert, but the the code for `do_CONNECT` seems only to handle a plain TCP relay, nothing near like what would be required to handle certificates or outgoing HTTPS connections.

Answer (score 0):

That blog is no way to write a proxy. It's very easy: you just accept a connection, read one line which tells you what to connect to, attempt the upstream connection, if it fails send the appropriate response and close the socket, otherwise just start copying bytes in both directions, *simultaneously,* until EOS has occurred in both directions. The only difference HTTPS makes is that you have to speak SSL instead of plaintext.

Comment: That might be ok for proxying a single request to a single server but proxying real traffic from a modern browser is more complicated.

Comment: @pguardiario It is OK for proxying anything the browser or the server can send. If you have counter-evidence please provide it.

Comment: well obviously it would need to multithread, keep track of connections with keep-alive, etc. etc..

Answer (score 0):

from my experience HTTPS is nowhere near "simple". Do you need a proxy that would catch traffic from your own machine? There are several applications, like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). Or google for alternatives. Comes with everything you need to debug the web traffic.

Comment: I updated my OP to clarify: I already use Charles (it's like Fiddler for OS X) and it's great for debugging web traffic.  But I want finer grained control over the filtering and presentation.

Comment: @fearless_fool what do you mean by "finer grained control"?

Comment: very specifically: I want to examine the forms, query strings and cookies of each outgoing request and then identify the previous responses in which those values originated.  Fine grained enough? :)

Comment: @fearless_fool, not sure what features do you have in Charles, but Fiddler let's you see all of that, i.e. forms, query strings and cookies. For each request you can see all request headers (what has been sent from your side) and response headers (what has been received). I.E. you can see everything that is being transmitted. Not sure what you mean by "identify the previous responses", as query strings and forms only are being sent (not received). Anyway, to build such a tool would take an enormous amount of time. I would suggest looking for something that is already built.

Comment: @fearless_fool anyway - let us know how it goes - this is definitely very interesting topic.