# Ruby MITM proxy

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, proxy, man-in-the-middle

I'm searching for some examples on how to write a proxy in Ruby that supports HTTPS. I have a simple proxy implemented with Webricks HTTPProxyServer, but I noticed, that HTTPS traffic is just tunneling (as it should ;) ). But I want to record the content with VCR (regarding my question here [VCRProxy: Record PhantomJS ajax calls with VCR inside Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039251/record-phantomjs-ajax-calls-with-vcr-inside-capybara)) and as long the content is only tunnled through, VCR can't record it.

So I was thinking of writing the proxy as a man-in-the-middle, generate SSL certificates on the fly (I don't care about certificate errors, its just for testing), and then I would be able to record the content / playback it later.

So if somebody has a good ressource from how to start, or a tutorial or a gist, please let me know.

PS: I have already seen this questions, but they don't provide any further stuff (and it need to be in ruby):

- [Man in the Middle (MITM) proxy with HTTPS support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129260/man-in-the-middle-mitm-proxy-with-https-support)
- [How do I write a simple HTTPS proxy server in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187509/how-do-i-write-a-simple-https-proxy-server-in-ruby)
- [Help with HTTP Intercepting Proxy in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679104/help-with-http-intercepting-proxy-in-ruby)

Answer (score 3):

An old question, but for the sake of completeness here goes another answer.

I've implemented a HTTP/HTTPS interception proxy in Ruby, the project is [hosted in github](https://github.com/argos83/ritm).

The project is new, so it's not (yet) as mature as Python's [mitmproxy](https://github.com/cortesi/mitmproxy), but it supports HTTPS with certificates generation on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent MITM proxy in Python aptly named [mitmproxy](https://github.com/cortesi/mitmproxy). The [netlib](https://github.com/cortesi/netlib) library by the author does the tricks and mitmproxy uses it.

The codebase isn't large and it shouldn't be hard to go through it given that you know Ruby.

Comment: I have seen that, but I need the proxy in ruby, because I must wrap a block around the net::http calls for VCR to record it.

Comment: I was suggesting that you should look at it for reference as your question implied that you were going to implement one in Ruby.

Comment: Thx, I will have a look at this, but my Python isn't very good ;), so when somebody got a ruby example, I would be glad to hear about it